# Linked questions page wrongly posts notifications for questions with new activity

Tags: bug, linked-questions

Linked questions pages (e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30687?sort=newest)) wrongly receive notifications of all new questions posted on the site. This is distracting.

Comment: Bug report on Meta Stack Exchange: [“Recently Active” linked questions updates incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209174). (Also: [Unexpected behavior of linked questions when sorted by recent activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266287) and [“x questions with new activity” is wrongfully showing in linked questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237227).0